# Create JSONL with Python

Tags: python-3.x, jsonlines

I can't figure out how to create [JSONL](http://jsonlines.org/) using Python3.

```
test = [{'a': 'b'}, {'a': 'b'}, {'a': 'b'}]

with open("data.json", 'w') as f:
    for item in test:
        json.dump(item, f)

with open("data.json") as f:
    for line in f:
        // only 1 line here! 
        print(line)

// prints
{"a": "b"}{"a": "b"}{"a": "b"}
```

I've tried using indent option to dump but it appears to make no different and the separators option don't seem to be a great usecase.  Not sure what I'm missing here?

Comment: Do you want each item in test as a new line in the output file?

Comment: @Rakesh yes that's exactly what i want.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use `.write` with newline `\n`

**Ex:**

```
import json
test = [{'a': 'b'}, {'a': 'b'}, {'a': 'b'}]

with open("data.json", 'w') as f:
    for item in test:
        f.write(json.dumps(item) + "\n")

with open("data.json") as f:
    for line in f:
        print(line)
```

Comment: You're right, was overthinking it - that does seem to be valid JSONL.  Thanks

Comment: You can also use jsonlines, or ndjson :)